# Trouble checking for duplicates in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know this has been asked multiple times but none of the answers I've seen help.  So here's my problem.

I have an array that get's dynamically populated depending on what is selected from a list.  At times, the array values that are pushed will have multiple values that are the same.  I want to take the values of that array, find if that value already exists in the array, and push it to a new array.  I have two global arrays that are defaulted to empty.

```
//Global arrays
var water_pipes_size_array = [];
var new_water_pipes_size_array  = [];
```

An example of what the `water_pipes_size_array` would look like is this:
`[0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 8, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

What I'm trying to do is search through this array and find any duplicate values and push them into the `new_water_pipes_size_array`.  However, what I have is not working.  I am still getting an empty array.

```
for(var j = 0; j < water_pipes_size_array - 1; j++){
    if(water_pipes_size_array[j + 1] == water_pipes_size_array[j]){
        new_water_pipes_size_array.push(water_pipes_size_array[j]);
    }
}
console.log(new_water_pipes_size_array);
```

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong and provide some feedback on how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean to put `water_pipes_size_array.length` in your for loop instead of `water_pipes_size_array`. Also, since you're starting at 0 you don't need to subtract 1:

```
for(var j = 0; j < water_pipes_size_array.length; j++){
    if(water_pipes_size_array[j + 1] == water_pipes_size_array[j]){
        new_water_pipes_size_array.push(water_pipes_size_array[j]);
    }
}
```

The logic is all wrong though. If you just want to eliminate duplicates, try this:

```
for (var j = 0; j < water_pipes_size_array.length; j++) {
    if (new_water_pipes_size_array.indexOf(water_pipes_size_array[j]) == -1) {
        new_water_pipes_size_array.push(water_pipes_size_array[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Crap.  Thank you.  I knew it was likely something simple.

Comment: Can you explain why it's checking if the index of the array is not equal to -1 though?

Comment: Ha, :).  I was wondering, wasn't making sense why I kept getting duplicates in the new array.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery there is nice way to achieve that

```
var water_pipes_size_array = [0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 8, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var new_water_pipes_size_array  = [];
new_water_pipes_size_array=$.map( water_pipes_size_array, function( value,index ) {
  return water_pipes_size_array[index+1]==value ? value : null;
});
console.log(new_water_pipes_size_array);
```